# Java regex split on multiple delimiters including substrings of other delimiters

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, split

I'm trying to convert a string into a map of values using regex and known delimiters. The code I have works, but if I use a delimiter which is a substring of another delimiter, it is not parsed (properly).

Let's cut straight to some sample input, erroneous output, expected output, and code!

Sample input: `"Artist: foo bar foooo Title: bar fooo bar Dimensions: x z y Framed dimensions: y z x"` (as you can see there is "Dimensions" and "Framed dimensions")

Erroneous output: `{Artist:=foo bar foooo, Title:=bar fooo bar, Dimensions:=x z y, dimensions:=y z x}` (Framed dimensions got caught under dimensions!)

Expected output: `Artist:=foo bar foooo, Title:=bar fooo bar, Dimensions:=x z y, Framed dimensions:=y z x}`

Code example:

```
String DELIMITER = "[Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|[Dd]imensions:"
...
public Map<String, String> parseToMap(String str) {
    Map<String, String> itemMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String infos[] = str.split("(?=" + DELIMITER + ')'); //split at delimiters
        for(String info : infos) {
            try {
                String[] tmp = info.split("(?<=" + DELIMITER + ')'); //split to key/val pair
                itemMap.put(tmp[0].trim(), tmp[1].trim());
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                //Skip if no key/val pair
            }
        }
    return itemMap;
}
```

I also feel like this is a bit hackish. If there is a more elegant solution, I'd be glad to hear it. Although I can always make a trip to CodeReview if we can just get this working for now :)

**EDIT:**
I need every word from delimiter to delimiter, not just the word following a delimiter.

Comment: In expected shouldn't it be `Title:=bar` instead of `Title=bar`?

Comment: You're absolutely right thanks for catching my typo!

Comment: See [another matching approach](https://ideone.com/9jMzVK)

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, your solution worked for me. Wanna make it an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @MeetTitan I added an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `split` operation use this regex with 2 captured groups:

```
(?<key>[\w\s]+:)\s*(?<value>.+?)\s*(?=(?:[Aa]rtist|[Tt]itle|(?:[Ff]ramed )?[Dd]imensions):|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7BAwn/3)

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "(?<key>[\\w\\s]+:)\\s*(?<value>.+?)\\s*(?=(?:[Aa]rtist|[Tt]itle|(?:[Ff]ramed )?[Dd]imensions):|$)";
final String string = "Artist: foo Title: bar Dimensions: x Framed dimensions: y";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);

Map<String, String> itemMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
while (m.find()) {
    itemMap.put(m.group("key"), m.group("value"));
}

System.out.println("itemMap: " + itemMap);
```

Comment: This only gets the following word. I need every word until the next delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is a non-consuming positive lookahead that tests *each* position inside a string, and thus, it can match overlapping strings.

You may use a *matching* approach to capture the delimiters into Group 1 and then any char that does not start any of the delimiters:

```
public static Map<String, String> parseToMap(String str) {
    String DESCRIPTION_DELIMITER = "[Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|[Dd]imensions:";
    Map<String, String> itemMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(" + DESCRIPTION_DELIMITER + ")((?:(?!" + DESCRIPTION_DELIMITER + ").)*)"); //split to key/val pair
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        itemMap.put(m.group(1).trim(), m.group(2).trim());
    }
    return itemMap;
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9jMzVK).

The regex will look like

```
([Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|[Dd]imensions:)((?:(?![Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|[Dd]imensions:).)*)
```

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQ1Bw6/1).

Here,

- `([Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|[Dd]imensions:)` - Group 1 matching any of the delimiters
- `((?:(?![Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|[Dd]imensions:).)*)` - a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any char other than a line break char (`.`),  0+ occurrences (`*`), that does not start any of the delimiter character sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is expected to be always in the following format
Artist: foo Title: bar Dimensions: x Framed dimensions: y

i.e, "D" is capital in Dimensions always, 
you can use 
String DELIMITER = "[Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|Dimensions:";
instead of 
String DELIMITER = "[Aa]rtist:|[Tt]itle:|[Ff]ramed [Dd]imensions:|[Dd]imensions:"